# Decrypt existing data From php to nodejs

Tags: php, node.js, express, cryptography

really need help with this. I have a project I'm working on in nodejs but the app has 2 different platforms(CodeIgniter and NodeJS) with the same database. I have a problem with decrypting the users' passwords in NodeJS. The 2 projects consist of different login forms but it only reads one database.

For the CodeIgniter part. These how the other devs use hash in passwords

```
function encryptIt( $password )
{
    $encrypt_method  = 'AES-256-CBC';
    $secret_key = 'This is my secret key';
    $key = hash('sha256', $secret_key);
    $secret_iv = 'This is my secret iv';
    $iv = substr(hash('sha256', $secret_iv), 0, 16);

    $this ->session->set_flashdata('iv', $iv);
    $this ->session->set_flashdata('key', $key);

    $qEncoded = base64_encode(openssl_encrypt($password, $encrypt_method, $key, 0, $iv));

    return( $qEncoded );

}

function decryptIt( $password )
{
    $decrypt_method = 'AES-256-CBC';

    $sess_data =  $this->session->userdata('logged_in');
    $iv = $sess_data['iv'];
    $key = $sess_data['key'];   
    
    $qDecoded = openssl_decrypt(base64_decode($password), $decrypt_method, $key, 0, $iv);
    return( $qDecoded );
}
```

And in my side, so far I'm trying things in how to decrypt the password in node.js, I'm using crypto. I've created an API also for receiving the request of username and password on the client-side. This is my code

```
const crypto = require('crypto');
// Defining key 
const key = crypto.randomBytes(32); 

// A decrypt function 
function decrypt(text) { 
  
  let iv = Buffer.from(text.iv, 'base64'); 
  let encryptedText = 
     Buffer.from(text.encryptedData, 'base64'); 
   
  // Creating Decipher 
  let decipher = crypto.createDecipheriv( 
         'aes-256-cbc', Buffer.from(key), iv); 
   
  // Updating encrypted text 
  let decrypted = decipher.update(encryptedText); 
  decrypted = Buffer.concat([decrypted, decipher.final()]); 
   
  // returns data after decryption 
  return decrypted.toString(); 
 } 

const express = require('express');
const router = express.Router();

const UserAccounts = require('../../models/user_account.model');


//@route /api/useraccounts/login
//@desc POST Get the data based in what username and password have entered
//@access public
router.post('/login', (req, res) => {

  //Username input
  const input = {
    username: req.body.USERNAME,
    password: req.body.PASSWORD
  };

  // check if the input is correct 
  UserAccounts.login(input, (err, data) => {
    if(err){
        res.status(400).json({
          account: 'User not found'
        });
    }

    else  {
      const passwordDecryption = data.PASSWORD.toString();
 
      console.log(decrypt(passwordDecryption)); 
    }
  });

});
```

But sadly it throws an error

```
TypeError [ERR_INVALID_ARG_TYPE]: The first argument must be of type string or an instance of Buffer, ArrayBuffer, or Array or an Array-like Object. Received undefined
```

Am I missing something in my code? or is there a better way to decrypt the password that is already hashed in the database? Thanks for someone who can help.

Comment: Without going deeper into an analyzis - on NodeJs-side you are generating a new random key - that can't work and the same key as on encryption side has to be used. Second: I don't see that the same iv is present on NodeJs-side. **Security warning**: your code is using a **static** iv that makes the encryption vulnerable and is **UNSECURE**. It's better to use a random iv and transport it along with the ciphertext to the recipient.

Comment: The key derivation (using a digest) in general seems to be missing in the NodeJS code.  Also it would be helpful if you describe the filling of `text`, because obviously the IV and the ciphertext are contained here. Best is to post an example for `$password`, `$secret_key` and `$secret_iv` including the generated ciphertext for the PHP code and the resulting parameters used in the NodeJS code. As a side note (because I don't know your architecture in detail), passwords should not be encrypted but hashed.

Comment: Hmm, I see. I'll work on that. For now, my priority is to decrypt the existing password so if the code is now working, I can now work on the security of the app. How can I decrypt the hash password just like the function decryptIt() in the CodeIgniter Side?

Comment: A prerequisite for successful decryption is to use the key and IV from the encryption. Both are derived in the PHP code from a passphrase using SHA256 (which is not very secure). This is missing in the NodeJS code, which can be implemented e.g. with the [`Hash`](https://nodejs.org/api/crypto.html#crypto_class_hash) class.

Comment: @Topaco thanks man for the idea. Really appreciated it. I'll keep in mind that.